# Why am I getting Handlebars is not defined when trying to compile?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Currently I am using flask with handlebars for javascript. For some reason I am getting 'define not defined' and 'handlebars is not defined'. Can someone give me some insight as to why?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.10/handlebars.amd.js" integrity="sha256-cEkEXgRFO7XYdrN1VzwFPP5zTTOxXJ2Xo6HoZos61Cs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

        <body>
           <script id="header" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
             <div> {{ headerTitle }} </div>
              Today is {{weekDay}}
           </script>
            <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

JS

```
$(function(){

var theData = {headerTitle:"Shop Page",
                    weekDay:"Wednesday"};
    var theTemplateScript = $("#header").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);
    var html = template(theData);

    console.log(html);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a build issue with the handlebars.js file.
If you look into the file you will see a lot of relative paths to different files as well as import statements.

Use this file to make it work - 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.10/handlebars.js